# Android mobile user agent?

Tags: android, webview, user-agent

I'm currently making an android application for a forum, basically it just loads the website in a webview and that works fine and all, but I'm trying to add an option to view the full site or the mobile site.

I got it working by just making a boolean BrowserType which when set to true, loads the mobile site in the webview, and when set to false, loads the full page. I already have it working and everything, the full site loads and I jsut have the user agent as "Chrome", and I set the mobile user agent to "Mobile", but that doesn't work, what am I supposed to use as the user agent for mobile? Just for reference, this is the method I'm using:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome");
```

Then for the mobile one instead of "Chrome", I used "Mobile". What is the correct user agent for mobile?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an example of user agent for android:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-gb; Nexus One Build/FRF50) 
AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

And you can use simply:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
```

Comment: When I do that, and I set the webview to Android, it just doesn't load anything, but when it's set to full it loads the full website.

Comment: does your site have a mobile version?

Answer (score 3):

As 2019 for Android devices have a look to: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

So as documentation says:

> WebView UA in Lollipop and Above
>
> In the newer versions of WebView, you can differentiate the WebView by
>   looking for the wv field as show in bold below.
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; **wv**)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65
>   Mobile Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

Create a new string
In the activity of the webview, create a new string,

```
String MyUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 " +
        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
```

So we created a string for user agent, the user agent defined in the string is of a desktop browser user agent, with this user agent set – your Android browser will load desktop version of websites. You can change this user agent to other user agents you like.

So we set the string, now let’s call it

```
web.getSettings().setUserAgentString(MyUA)
```

Here we called the string that we have set, it is ready now.

This code can be inside the oncreate method of the web activity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it works. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the existing accepted answer to the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.

Answer (score -7):

Use webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(int);
in the int parameter ,0 is a mobile browser while 1 is desktop browser