# Detect android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, uiwindow

I have an `html-javascript` page, and I need to detect whenever it open on web view (Like inside facebook webview, twitter webview, etc.), and if it a webview - display another content.

**Note:** I do not control the third-party Android apps, so I cannot make changes to their code.

I already found a way to detect an IOS webview (Found it on stackoverflow):

`var isIosWebview =/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`

Now I'm looking for a javascript code that can detect Android web view.

Help?

Comment: So you didn't find this and try something? https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent

Comment: I have tried before the link you attached. The "chrome/<version> Mobile" is exist on webview, but it also exist on regular android browser - So it not helping.

Comment: 'Version/4.0' seems to be unique to the Android WebView.

Comment: I'm getting on the first webview I checked (twitter) - Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile

Comment: I know IFrame is not supported only on web views, so there I have an indication - but I don't want to rely on this information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't detect it by only using the user agent string, as any app that uses WebView can set the UA string to anything it wants.

If you still insist on using the UA string, this is the explanation of the official docs: initially, Chromium-based WebView was using `.0.0.0` as Chrome version suffix; in the newer versions `; wv` was added into the platform part of the UA string. Note that pre-KitKat WebViews didn't have the `Chrome` part. See older posts about that: [Android, webview user agent vs browser user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727117/android-webview-user-agent-vs-browser-user-agent)

Another hint of WebView involvement is presence of `X-Requested-With` HTTP header with an application package name. Note that this header is also set by XMLHttpRequest, so you need to look for the actual value of the header.

The statement that WebView doesn't support iframes is not correct.

Comment: How do I get the "X-Requested-With" . I looked it up, and didn't found a good way to get it.

Comment: You can see it on the server. There is no way to see it from the page side.

Comment: in flask python, you can do `request.headers.get('X-Requested-With')` and it will give you the package name incase of webView. It helped me to block the apps which are illegally showing my website on webViews.

Answer (score 5):

The info others provided in this thread gave me what I needed to solve this problem in my case. For others, here is the resulting JS regex which represents the detection described in the accepted answer:

```
/(Version\/\d+.*\/\d+.0.0.0 Mobile|; ?wv|(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari))/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

The regex includes cases for old Android, new Android, iOS versions.

Comment: I just copy pasted this answer into our web view detection hook in our PWA. But it doesn't seem to detect old android phones, tested on my nexus 5x, android 8.1.0. Seems like everything prior to when they included the handy "wv"  in the user agent string doesn't get detected. Any input on this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it. It is very simple. Because there is an object used by Android web view to trigger functions in its Android app via javascript. So in your js code you can use:

```
if (typeof Android === "undefined") {
    // do something if is NOT a web view
} else {
    // do something else if is a web view
}
```

Comment: Thanks! From my recent experience, I realize that, whenever you use such an interface object in your javascript, you will want to perform this type of test to make sure you can at least test the look of your pages in a browser.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I have tried in an Android Webview inside of an emulator.

Comment: @gil.fernandes this code is JavaScript, it is not used in Android code

Comment: Tried this. JavaScript. Did not work for me in Facebook Android webview. (typeof Android === "undefined") apparently returned True

Answer (score -1):

I needed to detect if the browser was an Android WebView without using the User-Agent (since it can be spoofed), and without reading the Headers server-side.

It appears they were quite sneaky in hiding this, but you can check if the `window` has a property named `"Android "` (with a space at the end).  This appears to be `true` only when being used as a WebView inside an app, and not in Chrome on the same device.

```
const isAndroidWebView = window.hasOwnProperty('Android ')
```

**Disclaimer:** I have only verified this on a Pixel 3 running Android 10, and a Nokia 6 running Android 9.  Please comment if this does or doesn't work for your device.