# Prevent android app developers from opening my website in a Web View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

An unauthorized person has created an android app on our name, logo and showing our website content as is. It has fully functional browser experience in an app. This person is using advertisement to make money using our content.

Complaint to Google. No response so far.

Comment: Modify your webserver or core asp.net files (not sure which ones since you don't list version of .net) to include an x-frame header on all responses. 

`X-Frame-Options DENY`

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe

Comment: This question for JavaScript may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848320/detect-android-webview Check the presence and content of an "X-Requested-With" header in the request