# Hide Download Button in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, css

I want to show the download app now button on the website, but I want to hide that from webview android app. it should show up only on the website but not inside the webview app.

Is it possible? if so how?

**css file**

```
.desk {
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(35%, -25%);
    top: 50%; 
    right: 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 906px) {
     .desk {
          visibility:hidden;
     }
}
```

**html**

```
      <div class="desk">
 <a href="./download.php?file=app.apk" class="buttonDownload"><img src="img/playstore-app.jpg"  height="35" width="120">
</a>  

 </div>
```

**Main_activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://worldfamoushub.com");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('desk')[0].style.display='none';");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("Webview", "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

The problem is it will appear on all mobile. I want this button to be disappeared from android webview. Is it possible to show it in the mobile web browser but not inside the webview app?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029926/any-way-to-hide-elements-from-webview-android

Comment: Related: [Detect android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31848320/295004)

Comment: Try this: [Detecting mobile device in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Comment: can u point out the error in the code main_activity.java? 

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('desk')[0].style.display='none';");
... this doesn't seems to be doing its job correctly.