# Simple webview sample code Android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, interactive

I'm trying to make a simple webview app for this interactive map: http://gta5online.com/map-interactive > there is also a fullscreen link below the map.

Now I created an asset folder and included the "interactive" folder which has all the files, icons, map tiles and HTML document in it.

I want to load the HTML document from there into a activity as a webview. So its a local file. I want the app to handle it not the default browser.

Here is what I did by now:

I created a new project and added those codes into the activity_home.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Then I added this code to enable Internet access in to manifest even if its a local HTML doc that I want to load (for later uses):

I also enabled JavaScript at the first code block as you can see.

Should I've put some code into the home.java file too?

I try this but it gives errors:

```
 package comapps.gta5online.gta5interactivemapcheats;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
  }
 }

public class ViewWeb extends Activity {
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.webview);
      WebView wv;
      WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
      view.getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html");  
   }
 }
```

In a YT tutorial I saw that he used something like this in the Java file:

```
  #in mainactivity.java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String url ="file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html";
WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
view.getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a few imports. Replace all the code you have with this

```
package comapps.gta5online.gta5interactivemapcheats;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html");

 }

        private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: ok, i successed running it on a virtual nexus 5 device in the emulator myself. the code i have is much shorter though and i dont know if its all conform. how can i post code here. am i allowed to put it here since it wont show it as marked as code.

Comment: i will try with your code too. is there a way that the application user agent is used and not the default browser? thanks by the way

Comment: @serdox -- for user agent settings have a look here on how its done  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327160/android-mobile-user-agent  -- http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Android%20Webkit%20Browser/

Comment: ok my code was this. it worked: 'package comapps.gta5online.gta5interactivemapcheats;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;'

'

Comment: 'public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            String url ="file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html";
            WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
           view.getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           view.loadUrl(url);
           }
        }

Comment: what does your code do in addition to it, i try just to learn.

Comment: @serdox -- its ok to edit your question and add that code in as an Update. My code is just more organized, but there are many ways to write a webview

Comment: you also imported webkit and webclient my code didnt have this

Comment: hey i really appreciate this @Tasos

Comment: @serdox -- no probs you can click the up arrow to give a point for the help  -- take a look here as to what WebClient does -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: i did already :) but it wont show up because i have not the min. req. rep.

Comment: @serdox -- so basically (shouldOverrideUrlLoading) is used for other urls if you have any such as links -- return false;  -- use the webview -- return true; -- use the native browser on the mobile device. otherwise according to the doc you will get a popup window -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: yep. hey i found a error i've made that you also took over in your code because of me. the  WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); it should be R.id.webview at the end i guess. android studio says its wrong and it works when i write it all smallcaps as webview

Comment: @serdox --  That was a typo -- the id name is the id you given here (android:id="@+id/webview") -- so yes it should be (findViewById(R.id.webview); ) -- so if you had (android:id="@+id/jerry") then it should be (findViewById(R.id.jerry); )

Comment: thanks so much man. great help.made my day. my app is running hahaaa

Comment: i will post the link here for a screen capture.

Comment: @serdox -- that's great man. well if you ever find WebView lacks a bit of juice and Power you can always embed a Replacement Browser called Crosswalk which is  based on Google Chrome. Its fast, but because you are Embedding it it also adds 19 extra megs to the App. -- https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: i will bookmark it for later use. the emulator is just so slowly loading. i gave it 1 gb memory still.

Comment: hey @Tasos the video came out bright but you get the idea: https://youtu.be/qUNEpZbfRDM

Comment: @serdox - that looks great what you done with the map, well done

Comment: thanks @tasos. now i only need to find out how to add two more scrollable tabs, one with icons and descriptions and one with the cheats table. :D then there would be a adsense/admob banner displayed on the side or below. that would be everything hehe. let's see.

Comment: @serdox -- You need tabs and fragments -- a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJeeZHFgLfc